# Contacts without channel addresses deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, delete, contactbuilder, data-extract

I have extracted the contacts without channel adresses in Marketing Cloud and while trying to delete them (over 2 million), the deletion couldn't be processed as the maximum contact that could be deleted per request is One million.
Any solution to suggest me?
Thank you

Comment: Extract top 1 million and repeat?

Comment: You mean I need to filter the DE as to start with only 1 million?

Comment: You can use `SELECT TOP 1000000` in your query to get the first million. Delete it and then rerun the query yo get the rest and delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage the [Random Data extension](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_random_de.htm&language=en_US&type=5) feature in marketing cloud and split the DE into 3+ segments

> A random data extension splits up subscribers from a selected standard data extension and places the subscribers into new data extensions in Marketing Cloud Email Studio. You can create as many as 12 data extensions at a time.